# Knockout validation does not work in every computer

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am working on a project which I need to validate, but it does not work in every computer, in my computer on IE and Google Chrome it works perfectly and the code enables the button but on other computers which have current versions on IE or Chrome it does not enable the button.

Here is my Knockout validation settings:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
ko.validation.init({
    registerExtenders: true,
    messagesOnModified: false,
    insertMessages: true,
    parseInputAttributes: true
});
//ko.validation.registerExtenders();
ko.applyBindings();
```

and this is my validation method:

```
var myNewBusiness = function (Country_ImportFrom, Country_ExportTo, State_ProducedIn, State_HandIn, State_SentTo, MainActivity, BusinessType, MainService, Currency,CountryId_ImportFrom, CountryId_ExportTo, StateId_ProducedIn, StateId_HandIn, StateId_SentTo,
FormName, Email, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, Price, Address, MainActivityId, YearsOfActivity
, Website, Capacity ,Comments, Company, CurrencyId,BusinessTypeId, StatusTypeId, BusinessId, MainServiceId, PersonId, ProtNum, Tags, ImageData
  ) {
    var self = this;

    var
        _Currency = ko.observable(Currency),
        _ProtNum = ko.observable(ProtNum),
        _Country_ImportFrom = ko.observable(Country_ImportFrom),
        _Country_ExportTo = ko.observable(Country_ExportTo),
        _State_ProducedIn = ko.observable(State_ProducedIn),
        _State_HandIn = ko.observable(State_HandIn),
        _State_SentTo = ko.observable(State_SentTo),
        _MainActivity = ko.observable(MainActivity),
        _BusinessType = ko.observable(BusinessType),
        _MainService = ko.observable(MainService),
        _BusinessTypeId = ko.observable(BusinessTypeId).extend({ required: { params: true, message: "این فیلد الزامی است" } }),//, getBusinessTypeId: {params: true} 
        _CountryId_ImportFrom = ko.observable(CountryId_ImportFrom)
        .extend({
            required: {
                onlyIf: function () {
                    if (clientModel)
                        return clientModel.selectedProtNum() === 101;
                    else
                        return false;
                }, params:clientModel, message: "این فیلد الزامی است"
            }

        })
        ,
        _CountryId_ExportTo = ko.observable(CountryId_ExportTo)
        .extend({
            required: { onlyIf: function () {
                if (clientModel)
                    return clientModel.selectedProtNum() === 104;
                else
                    return false;
            }, params:clientModel,  message: "این فیلد الزامی است" }

        })
        ,
        _StateId_ProducedIn = ko.observable(StateId_ProducedIn)
        .extend({
            required: {
                onlyIf: function () {
                    if (clientModel)
                        return clientModel.selectedProtNum() === 103;
                    else
                        return false;
                }, params: clientModel, message: "این فیلد الزامی است"
            }

        })
        ,
        _StateId_HandIn = ko.observable(StateId_HandIn)
        .extend({
            required: {
                onlyIf: function () {
                    if (clientModel)
                        return clientModel.selectedProtNum() === 101;
                    else
                        return false;
                }, params: clientModel, message: "این فیلد الزامی است"
            }

        })
        ,
        _StateId_SentTo = ko.observable(StateId_SentTo)
        .extend({
            required: {
                onlyIf: function () {
                    if (clientModel)
                        return clientModel.selectedProtNum() === 104;
                    else
                        return false;
                }, params: clientModel, message: "این فیلد الزامی است"
            }

        })
        ,
         _Capacity = ko.observable(Capacity).extend({ number: true, min: 1 })

        ,  
        _FormName = ko.observable(FormName).extend({
            required: {message: "این فیلد الزامی است"}, params: true
        }),
        _Email = ko.observable(Email).extend({  pattern: { message: "قالب ایمیل را رعایت کنید", params: /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i } }),
        _FirstName = ko.observable(FirstName),
        _LastName = ko.observable(LastName),
        _PhoneNumber = ko.observable(PhoneNumber).extend({ pattern: { message: "قالب تلفن را رعایت کنید", params: /^\+?([0-9]{2})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{6})$/ } }), 
        _Price = ko.observable(Price).extend({ number: true, min: 1 }),
        _Address = ko.observable(Address),
        _MainActivityId = ko.observable(MainActivityId).extend({
            required: {
                onlyIf: function () {
                    if (clientModel)
                        return clientModel.selectedProtNum() === 101 || clientModel.selectedProtNum() === 102 || clientModel.selectedProtNum() === 103 || clientModel.selectedProtNum() === 104 || clientModel.selectedProtNum() === 105;
                    else
                        return false;
                }, params: clientModel, message: "این فیلد الزامی است"
            }

        }),
        _YearsOfActivity = ko.observable(YearsOfActivity).extend({ number: true, min: 1 }),
        _Website = ko.observable(Website).extend({ pattern: { message: "قالب آدرس وب را رعایت کنید مثال: www.google.com", params: /^(www\.){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}[\.]{0,1}/ } }), 

        _Comments = ko.observable(Comments),
        _Company = ko.observable(Company),
        _CurrencyId = ko.observable(CurrencyId).extend({ required: { params: true, message: "این فیلد الزامی است" } }),
        _StatusTypeId = ko.observable(StatusTypeId),
        _BusinessId = ko.observable(BusinessId),
        _MainServiceId = ko.observable(MainServiceId).extend({
            required: {
                onlyIf: function () {
                    if (clientModel)
                        return clientModel.selectedProtNum() === 100;
                    else
                        return false;
                }, params: clientModel, message: "این فیلد الزامی است"
            }

        }),
        _PersonId = ko.observable(PersonId),
    _Tags = ko.observable(Tags),
    _ImageData = ko.observable(ImageData);
    var BusinessErrors = ko.validation.group([       
        _FormName
        , _Email
        , _PhoneNumber
        , _Price
        , _YearsOfActivity
        , _Website
        , _BusinessTypeId
      , _StateId_SentTo
      , _StateId_HandIn
      , _StateId_ProducedIn
      , _CountryId_ExportTo
      , _CountryId_ImportFrom
      , _MainActivityId
     , _MainServiceId
     , _Capacity
     , _CurrencyId
    ]);

    return {

        CountryId_ImportFrom: _CountryId_ImportFrom,
        CountryId_ExportTo: _CountryId_ExportTo,
        StateId_ProducedIn: _StateId_ProducedIn,
        StateId_HandIn: _StateId_HandIn,
        StateId_SentTo: _StateId_SentTo,
        FormName: _FormName,
        Email: _Email,
        FirstName: _FirstName,
        LastName: _LastName,
        PhoneNumber: _PhoneNumber,
        Price: _Price,
        Address: _Address,
        MainActivityId: _MainActivityId,
        YearsOfActivity: _YearsOfActivity,
        Website: _Website,
        Capacity: _Capacity,
        Comments: _Comments,
        Company: _Company,
        CurrencyId: _CurrencyId,
        BusinessTypeId: _BusinessTypeId,
        StatusTypeId: _StatusTypeId,
        BusinessId: _BusinessId,
        MainServiceId: _MainServiceId,
        PersonId: _PersonId,
        Country_ImportFrom:_Country_ImportFrom,
        Country_ExportTo : _Country_ExportTo,
        State_ProducedIn: _State_ProducedIn,
        State_HandIn : _State_HandIn,
        State_SentTo : _State_SentTo,
        MainActivity : _MainActivity,
        BusinessType :_BusinessType,
        MainService: _MainService,
        Currency: _Currency,
        ProtNum: _ProtNum,
        Tags: _Tags,
        ImageData : _ImageData,
        BusinessErrors: BusinessErrors,

    };


};
```

and this is my viewModel:

```
var clientModel = {
    newBusiness: myNewBusiness("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "","","","","","","","","", ""),
}
```

and the HTML code that checks the errors:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" data-bind=" enable:!clientModel.newBusiness.BusinessErrors().length">ایجاد</button>
```

this

Comment: What computer (browser/OS) does it not work on? What errors do you get?

Comment: On windows 10 and latest version of IE and chrome, It is supposed to enable the button but it does not!!!!